# How do I configure a Jenkins "New Item" to push a file to a specific server on the network?

Tags: python, linux, networking, jenkins, build

I have Jenkins installed on a Linux server. It can run builds on itself. I want to create either a Freestyle Project or an External Job that transfers a Python script and runs it on two separate linux servers. Where in the GUI do I configure the destination server when I create a build?

I have added "nodes" in the GUI. I can see the free space of the servers in the Jenkins GUI, so I know the credentials work. But when I create a build, I see no field that would tell Jenkins to push the Python script to a specific server.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestions:

Label all relevant nodes with a label (ex. python, python_script, etc), then

**Option 1**

1. Install [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)
2. Create a job that triggers the job that does the script transfer and set the node label parameter to be triggered on the required label:
   [image]
   This would make the triggered job run on all nodes with the label you set in the node label parameter (python in my example).

**Option 2**

3. Install [Matrix Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) and [Elastic Axis](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Elastic+Axis)
4. Create a multi configuration job with an elastic axis that uses the python label:
   [image]
5. (that job should also do the script transfer)

This multi configuration job would run on all nodes with the label you set in the elastic axis (python in my example).